# I want to make a list of items and sub-items with the first item number of my choice

Tags: enumerate, itemize

While writing a list, how can I get the following as output:

```
N.1 String 1
N.2 String 2
N.3 String 3
    N.3.1 String a
    N.3.2 String b
```

etc. Here N is the number of my choice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11):

It's easy with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=N.\arabic*]
  \item String 1
  \item String 2
  \item String 3
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
    \item String a
    \item String b
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the inner `enumerate`, `label*` is used to inherit the label from the outer one.